# AHBot in an AzerothCore 3.3.5 Server

Tags: emulation, azerothcore

Does anyone have a guide on setting up AHBot in an [AzerothCore](http://www.azerothcore.org/) 3.3.5 server? I can find no mention of ahbot in the world.conf and no DB tables like auctionhousebot in the database or any references. It is included in TrinityCore so all the google references that I find point me back there.

Our server is just two of us and it would be nice to have some items on the auction house. At the moment, if you need a silver bar you have to go out in the world and find it. That was exciting the first couple of times... but gets old.

I followed the guide to install off github: https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Installation and am using the latest release under Ubuntu linux.

Thank you for any help. You are my last hope...

Answer (score 1):

AHBot is not currently an 'official' supported module of AzerothCore (which would be why you aren't finding any settings in the worldserver or anywhere else regarding it).

There is a module in development that isn't currently part of the AC list, but I've gotten it working on my personal server:  https://github.com/AyaseCore/mod-ahbot Note that this is a bit different than a normal module as there is also a git patch that needs to be applied manually.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a module in azerothCore repository you have to apply patch manually but it wont compile on Win x64 and unix x64 comes up with an error about 9 arguments, but seems to compile for some